# HTML textarea positioning with css

Tags: html, css, textarea

i am currently trying to position a textarea with CSS and to make it look nice. However it's not working.

Relevant CSS:

```
#BoardInput {
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#BoardSmiley {
min-width:100px;
width:20%;
padding:10px;
border-right:thin solid #4E6011;
border-bottom:thin solid #4E6011;
background-color:#C6E466;
}
#BoardCode {
 border:thin solid #4E6011;
background-color:#C6E466;
padding:3px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="BoardCode">
    <button onclick="addBBCode('[FETT]','[/FETT]');">Fett</button>
    <button onclick="addBBCode('[KURSIV]','[/KURSIV]');">Kursiv</button>
    <button onclick="addBBCode('[UNTERSTRICHEN]','[/UNTERSTRICHEN]');">Unterstrichen</button>
    <button onclick="addLink();">Link</button>
    <button onclick="addImage();">Bild</button>
</div>
<form action="index.php?s=board&action=addedit&where=<?=$Result['Overview']['PostID']?>" method="POST">
<table id="Board">
    <tr>
        <td>
              <textarea id="BoardInput" name="Text"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="ThreadID" value="<?=$Result['Overview']['ThreadID']?>" />
        </td>
        <td id="BoardSmiley">
        <?php
        $BoardTemplate->showSmileys();
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="2">
         <td><input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The problem is that i want the "Code" Box at the top, the Smileys-Box at the right and the textarea at the left. And i want them to be fully adjusted to each other. However the textarea is 1px more intented to the right than the Code box above and 2px more intented to the top than the Smileys-Box on the right.

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/SSxSN](http://jsfiddle.net/SSxSN) and an image:

[image]

Comment: Is this _really_ tabular data?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using tables?

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's of course not really tabular data. It's just an "add post form". How else can i make sure this thing looks like i want? jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SSxSN/ and an image: http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3234/3f6dkhpc_png.htm

Comment: Can you send us a link to what it looks like or post a screenshot?  Also what do you mean by "nice" that's a bit vague

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```css
resize:none;
```

in your css code in textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Add negative margins for left and bottom, like this:

```
#BoardInput {
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 0 -8px -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSxSN/1/

Comment: Question is: Why is this needed? Why won't it work with just an ordinary padding:0?

Comment: because padding only affects the space within the objects' borders whereas the margins affect the space outside the objects' borders...